# Will Path of Exile accounts be wiped after beta?

Tags: path-of-exile

I'm thinking on supporting [Path of Exile](http://www.pathofexile.com/) to get a Beta testing key.

However I want to know whether the account/characters are being wiped after beta.

This is important to determine how much time I should invest on Beta.

Comment: You should probably ask on their forums instead of here, as that's only place you are likely to get an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Already found [the answer](https://www.pathofexile.com/purchase):

> Although you're buying Beta access, your characters and items will
>   still be wiped along with the rest of the Beta characters when we
>   enter Open Beta. If we wipe characters or move them to a "Legacy
>   League" for technical or balance reasons before Open Beta, your
>   characters will be affected along with everyone else. Purchasing Beta
>   access does not entitle you to any special treatment in game and you
>   can still be muted or banned for inappropriate behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

This is also shown in the launcher, clarifying the situation a little more:

> As part of the process of entering Open Beta, we have wiped all characters and reverted them to level 1 so that their names are retained. All items have been destroyed apart from the Unique prize item "Demigod's Presence" and Kiwi pets. There will never be another character or item wipe.

From this, I believe that the wipe that recently happened during the transition into Open Beta will be the last wipe that is ever made. Those who played Closed Beta still get to keep their character names.

Comment: Last wipe = confirmed [here](http://www.pathofexile.com/forum/view-thread/70299). *"All characters will be reverted to level 1 and moved to new Default and Hardcore leagues. Their items will be destroyed, other than Demigod's Presences and pets. This is the final wipe the game will ever have."* (23 January 2013)

Comment: Awesome! I'm surprised the aren't doing another wipe after Open Beta but I'm not about to complain :D